# How do I get information about the file/folder that has been right clicked BEFORE my OSX Service is displayed?

Tags: objective-c, macos, finder, contextmenu

I am contemplating the creation of an OSX System Service as outlined here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html My understanding is that I can add items to the Finder's right-click menu using this method.

The only big question mark in my mind is whether I can conditionally show my service `NSMenuItem` based on the item that is getting right-clicked. I don't see a way to do this in the docs, am I just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000852-CHDJDFIC). You can’t run any code in advance, but you can use the `NSSendFileTypes` to specify an array of UTIs (which identify file types) that your service accepts.

Comment: Thank you for this. I must have looked at this page 50 times already, and since I've never worked with UTIs before, that didn't really sink in before.